# Removed spam or R/A sometimes has its title visible in mobile Page Not Found page

Tags: bug, mobile-web, spam, offensive

This only shows up *sometimes*, however.

[image]

Comment: And how does it look like in full site? No such link in there?

Comment: No, no links whatsoever.